# Training a tensorflow 1 model with the object detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Im trying to train the ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md with tensorflow 2 but i get the error
**ValueError: ssd_inception_v2 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow.**
I tried creating a new enviroment with tensorflow 1.15 and installed the object detection api on it using object_detection/packages/tf1/setup.py thinking this would resolve the problem because im installing the object detection api for tensorflow 1 (or so i believe) but when trying to train i get the same error. Im using the files model_main.py, model_main_tf2.py, and legacy train.py but to no avail. I would think that im using the wrong files to train a tensorflow 1 model but i cant find any documentation on that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the script object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf1_test.py ? My guess is you haven't done the installation properly for Tensorflow 1 and that the python files generated with the proto command are not generated well or something like that. If you want to use TF2 check the model zoo corresponding : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md. You could also retry the installation with a docker image for exemple : https://gilberttanner.com/blog/installing-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please go to [tf1 installation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1.md) and follow **Python Package Installation**. once you run the test below sucessfully, you are good to go for using tensorflow object detection api on you system.

```
# Test the installation.
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf1_test.py
```

Use [tf1_detection_zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md) models, If you still come across any error, you can share it.

Comment: yes, the problem was my tensorflow 1.15 was override by a wild 2.3 installation . Re-installed and all is good

Comment: That's good to know. For working on different tensor-flow versions, always use different virtual environments.